# Adding custom field to devise User model error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, strong-parameters

i'm adding a full_name (string) value to my model User, using gem Devise.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Authorization
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

And also

```
# app/controllers/concerns/Authorization.rb

module Authentication
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  private

  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    if resource_class == User
      User::ParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)
    else
      super
    end

  end
end


# app/controllers/sanitizers/user/parameter_sanitizer.rb

class User
  class ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
    USER_PARAMS = %i(
      full_name
      email
      password
      password_confirmation
    ).freeze

    def sign_up
      default_params.permit(USER_PARAMS)
    end

    def account_update
      default_params.permit(USER_PARAMS)
    end
  end
end
```

Everything should work, but I've got an error when creating user
`Unpermitted parameter: full_name`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that `USER_PARAMS` is an array.

```
USER_PARAMS
# => [:full_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]
```

But you need to permit attributes like

```
permit(:full_name, :email, :password, ...)
```

So you can try to do

```
default_params.permit(*USER_PARAMS)
```

**UPDATE**

Check out devise [source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L2-L34).
It seems like you can use `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit` to allow additional keys for example for `:sign_up` action.
Like

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:full_name])
```

Note that devise already defines some `DEFAULT_PERMITTED_ATTRIBUTES` so you don't need to redefine them.

So I think the following code should work for you

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:full_name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:full_name])
  end
end
```

Comment: still same problem

Comment: The problem is definetely with strong parameters. Do you still have `Unpermitted parameter: full_name`?

Comment: yes, still the same error, all day trying to solve the problem

Comment: I will try to reproduce the problem for myself to give 100% sure answer. By the way maybe you can share your code?